# Deliver images in Django from a different path than from its ImageField.url property

Tags: python, django

I'm porting a web app from PHP (Codeigniter) to Python (powered by Django.) I already migrated the database and am now using Django models. I populated the database with images using Django's ImageField field and the images are in its proper folders under `MEDIA_ROOT`.

I'm in development so I'm using Django's server to test the web app as I go and I can serve the images through `image.url`.

`image.url` serves the image from:

`MEDIA_ROOT/folder/subfolder/numberImage_folder_subfolder.jpg`

But I need it to be served from `MEDIA_ROOT/numberImage_folder_subfolder.jpg`.

In production I know I can serve the image using **nginx**'s [XSendFile](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/) or something like that. Django's server (runserver command) is very easy to use and gives me what I need at the moment. *While in development, how can I deliver the image from the URL I require?* Preferably using Django's server...

Any help will be so much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what your URLs are and how they map to file paths (and don't have the reputation to ask for clarification yet).  So correct me if I've understood it wrong.

But in the meantime, to rephrase the question slightly, I think you're saying that you have the files stored on disk in those subfolders like `MEDIA_ROOT/folder/subfolder/numberImage_folder_subfolder.jpg`, but when you actually want the URLs served, you don't want the folders in the URL, so the URL will have `MEDIA_ROOT/numberImage_folder_subfolder.jpg`? And only with the `./manage.py runserver`?

Going ahead on those assumptions, we have two steps: map the URLs we want back to a file path, and then also make sure we're generating the URLs we want.

---

**For the first**, normally urls.py will have something like this to serve media files in development:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
if settings.DEBUG is True:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

which is basically adding `url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', django.views.static.serve)` to your urlconf, where `serve` takes all paths below `settings.MEDIA_URL` and serves up the equivalent file under `MEDIA_ROOT`.

The simplest way to do this would be to create a custom function modelled on that same [`django.conf.urls.static`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10/django/conf/urls/static.py) which takes the path and adds the folders back in before passing it on to `django.views.static.serve`.

---

**For the second**, if you want the URLs generated from the ImageField.url to differ from the underlying file storage path, you'll need to have a custom ImageField subclass overriding the [`FileField.url` property](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L67) (or a custom Storage class that does a similar thing).

Like so:

```
class CustomURLImageField(django.forms.fields.ImageField):
    def _get_url(self):
        """
        Override the standard FileField.url property to mangle the URL from 
            MEDIA_ROOT/folder/subfolder/numberImage.jpg
        to
            MEDIA_ROOT/numberImage_folder_subfolder.jpg
        """
        self._require_file()
        #return self.storage.url(self.name)
        path_components = self.name.split('/')
        folder = path_components[-3]
        subfolder = path_components[-2]
        numberImage, ext = os.path.splitext(path_components[-1])
        return '/{numberImage}_{folder}_{subfolder}{ext}'.format(**locals())
    url = property(_get_url)
```

This will be likely true in production too... how are you generating your URLs?)